# Email sending without attachment - Python 3.8

Tags: python, email, attachment

1. I want to send a .txt file attached to the mail in Python.
   Currently the mail is received but without any attachment.
2. Code bellow
3. I've sent emails in PHP but Python is completely new to me
4. The code doesn't return any errors, it simply doesn't send the attachment with the email

```
   with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
       server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
       smtp.ehlo()
       smtp.starttls()
       smtp.ehlo()
       msg = MIMEMultipart()

       smtp.login(EMAIL_ADRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
       subject = 'Log Register'

       
       filename = 'logs-to-h4wtsh0wt.txt'
       attachment = open(filename, 'rb')
       part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
       part.set_payload(attachment.read())
       encoders.encode_base64(part)
       part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= "+filename)
       msg.attach(part)
       msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{Body}'
       smtp.sendmail(EMAIL_ADRESS,EMAIL_ADRESS, msg)
```

Comment: Tell us what's wrong with your code, do you get any errors or misfunctionality?

Comment: also i should add that the code doesn't return any errors, it just doesn't send the attachment

Comment: You're overwiting the `msg` object.

Comment: How can i correct that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

snakecharmerb is right. You are indeed overriding the message object and therefore losing everything you add before that point.

You can instead set the subject like this:

```
msg['Subject'] = "Subject of the Mail"

# string to store the body of the mail 
body = "Body_of_the_mail"
  
# attach the body with the msg instance 
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
```

Because you are attaching a file you will also need to convert the multipart message into a string before sending:

```
text = msg.as_string()

smtp.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
```

When you created `msg` with `MIMEMultipart()` it generated the message object structure for you as per [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822.html) which also gives you `FROM`, `TO`, etc.

The msg object also has a bunch of functions you can run outlined in its [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message)

Comment: to evankaropoulos and snakecharmerb , thanks guys <3 it's working now my first python program is finally complete, much love <3